# Index out of range on Table Refresh?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I added refreshing capabilities for my tableView when the user pulls down on it. This works most of the time but occasionally I'll get a fatal error, `Index out of range`. The callback thats called to refresh the table does the following:

1) Empty's out data structures holding data to be displayed

2) Fetch data from Firebase database

3) Parse data into individual parts and insert into data structures

4) Refresh the table

However, in the `cellForRowAt indexPath` function of my tableView I'm getting the fatal error on the first line of the function:

`let eventsOnDay = eventsForDate[allDates[indexPath.section]]!`

Here's my code for the refresh callback:

```
var allDates = [DateStruct]()                    // Holds all unique dates of events
var eventsForDate = [DateStruct : [PetEvent]]()  // Holds all events for each day

///  Read events from db, split into individual dates
///
func readEventsFromDb() {
 // 1. Empty out data structures
        eventsForDate.removeAll()
        allDates.removeAll()

        let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("pets").child(currentPet).child("events")
 // 2. Fetch data from db
        dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
 // 3. Split data into individual components
                for child in snapshots{
                    if let data = child.value as? [String: Any] {
                        if let c = data["comment"] as? String, let p = data["user"] as? String, let t = data["type"] as? Int, let d = data["date"] as? UInt64 {
                            let event = PetEvent(comment: c, person: p, type: t, time: self.timeFromEpoch(time: Double(d)))
                            let eventDate = self.dateFromEpoch(time: Double(d))
                            if (self.eventsForDate[eventDate] != nil) {
                                self.eventsForDate[eventDate]!.append(event)
                            } else {
                                self.eventsForDate[eventDate] = [event]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.allDates = Array(self.eventsForDate.keys).sorted {d1,d2 in
                    d2 < d1
                }
 // 4. Reload table
                self.feedTable.reloadData()
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }
        })
    }
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out why this is working most of the time but occasionally fails. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to avoid the crash you can safely check for your `eventOnDelay` item by doing something like this:

```
if allDates.count > indexPath.section {
    guard let eventsOnDay = eventsForDate[allDates[indexPath.section]] else {
        //handle error here...
        return
    }
    //Do whatever you need with eventsOnDay here
} else {
    //Check your numberOfSections method, as it's not set up correctly
}
```

You also definitely need to make sure you're calling `tableView.reloadData()` and `endRefreshing` on the main thread as your Firebase callback likely comes back on a bg thread.

Comment: I'm not doing anything special with threads for the `reloadData()`, so I'd assume its on the main thread.

Comment: @MarksCode I would be surprised if that is true, but you'll see warnings in the debugger if I'm correct.  It's worth being explicit, as it's only 2 extra lines of code to guarantee it's on the main thread.  Up to you though.

Answer (score 2):

check wether the array(containing data to display) is not empty in your tableview's delegate and datasource method.

i.e. in cellForRow method

```
 check if(yourArray.count > 0){
      // Do your code
   }
 else{
     // Dont
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use different approach to update the table view content. I think there is delay getting data from firebase you are using callback dbRef.observeSingleEvent. you are removing the previous data at the beginning of the function call. you can try following two approaches to fix the issue

### 1. Remove empty data in dbRef.observeSingleEvent callback

```
var allDates = [DateStruct]() // Holds all unique dates of events
var eventsForDate = [DateStruct : [PetEvent]]()  // Holds all events for each day

//  Read events from db, split into individual dates
func readEventsFromDb() {
let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("pets").child(currentPet).child("events")
// 1. Fetch data from db
 dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
 if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
 // 2. Empty out data structures
  eventsForDate.removeAll()
  allDates.removeAll()
  // 3. Split data into individual components
  for child in snapshots{
                if let data = child.value as? [String: Any] {
                    if let c = data["comment"] as? String, let p = data["user"] as? String, let t = data["type"] as? Int, let d = data["date"] as? UInt64 {
                        let event = PetEvent(comment: c, person: p, type: t, time: self.timeFromEpoch(time: Double(d)))
                        let eventDate = self.dateFromEpoch(time: Double(d))
                        if (self.eventsForDate[eventDate] != nil) {
                            self.eventsForDate[eventDate]!.append(event)
                        } else {
                            self.eventsForDate[eventDate] = [event]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.allDates = Array(self.eventsForDate.keys).sorted {d1,d2 in
                d2 < d1
            }
 // 4. Check if this is on UI/Main thread. Reload table
            self.feedTable.reloadData()
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }
    })
}
```

### 2. Use temporary arrays to hold the data and then update the main data with temporary array

```
//Read events from db, split into individual dates
func readEventsFromDb() {
    let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("pets").child(currentPet).child("events")
  // 1. Fetch data from db
    dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot]       {
        var tempAllDates = [DateStruct]()   // Holds all unique dates of events
        var tempEventsForDate = [DateStruct : [PetEvent]]()
   // 2. Split data into individual components
            for child in snapshots{
                if let data = child.value as? [String: Any] {
                    if let c = data["comment"] as? String, let p = data["user"] as? String, let t = data["type"] as? Int, let d = data["date"] as? UInt64 {
                        let event = PetEvent(comment: c, person: p, type: t, time: self.timeFromEpoch(time: Double(d)))
                        let eventDate = self.dateFromEpoch(time: Double(d))
                        if (self.tempEventsForDate[eventDate] != nil) {
                            self.tempEventsForDate[eventDate]!.append(event)
                        } else {
                            self. tempEventsForDate[eventDate] = [event]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self. tempAllDates = Array(self.eventsForDate.keys).sorted {d1,d2 in
                d2 < d1
            }
    // 3. Empty out data structures
           eventsForDate.removeAll()
        allDates.removeAll()

    // 4. Fill data with temporary array. check the size 
        if tempEventsForDate.count > 0{
            eventsForDate = tempEventsForDate 
        }
        if tempAllDates.count > 0{
            allDates =  tempAllDates
        }

   // 5. Check if this is on UI/Main thread. Reload table
            self.feedTable.reloadData()
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }
    })
}
```

Hope this approaches will help to solve the issue :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say "you are removing the previous data at the beginning of the function call". I'm emptying out the arrays at the start on purpose, so when the firebase finishes fetching it starts populating empty data structures

Comment: @Mark Are there any specific scenarios where application is getting crash like while scrolling table view when data is updating in background or if you keep open application for longer time its getting crash ?